# Extract date from Image and filter dataframe with date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm working on Image Recognition. There are a lot of video taken from security cameras and I need to know someone on the camera.

I'm trying to create the training kit right now. For this purpose, I've divided the videos into frames. Then I pulled the date of entry and extracted. Like this;

[image]

My goal here is to compare the entry date with the database and define the square. So I can use the photo of the person who entered that hour as a training set.

For this purpose, I keep the data from the database in pandas dataframe. Because I have the database data in csv format.

I want to date and filter on dataframe by this date but it doesn't happen. The code I use is as follows;

```
result = tur_[(tur_['Date'] > datetime_object) & (tur_['Date'] <= added_datetime_object)]
```

datetime_object is extracted date, 
added_datetime_object = datetime_object + 3 seconds

If I filter dataframe like this it's working;

```
result = tur_[(tur_['Date'] > datetime_object)]
```

But this code return empty dataframe;

```
result = tur_[(tur_['Date'] <= added_datetime_object)]
```

The last thing, `tur_['Date']` column like this;

[image]

Comment: What is `print (tur_['Date'].dtype)` ?

Comment: Sorry, first tur_['Date].dtype is object then I convert it. I use this code; tur_['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(tur_['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: Ok, it looks super, what is `added_datetime_object` ? How is created?

Comment: added_datetime_object = datetime_object + 3 seconds

Comment: Ok, so what is `print (type(datetime_object))` ?

Comment: datetime64, and tur_['Date'].dtype datetime64[ns] after convertion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185610/discussion-between-jezrael-and-kerim-caner-tumkaya).